# Sql db2 database

Tags: sql, db2

Which date function use to convert date format 
 YYYYMMDD TO   DDMMYYYY

I am using db2 database please help me

Answer (score 0):

assuming you column_with_date is a valid date column and if you have  DB2 9.7,  you  could use

```
date(to_date(column_with_date,'DDMMYYYY'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

`to_char(datecol,'DDMMYYYY')`

just to display as `DDMMYYYY`

a date column doesn't have a format( not stored with a format within a DB table)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your column's data type is VARCHAR, convert it to date and then format it to `DDMMYYYY`:

```
varchar_format((to_date(col, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'DDMMYYYY')
```

replace `col` with your column's name.
Or use [`substr()`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_substr.html) and concatenation:

```
substr(col, 7, 2) || substr(col, 5, 2) || substr(col, 1, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

2 ways to do it that I can think of, already mentioned above but giving a real command so you can try it.

db2 "select to_char(current_date,'DDMMYYYY') from sysibm.sysdummy1"

or

db2 "select varchar_format(current_date,'DDMMYYYY') from sysibm.sysdummy1"